# Parametrizing with class method, then calling that method with object

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing

(pseudo-code)
I have class Node with properties:

```
class Node(WebElement):

    def __init__(self, element):
        super().__init__(element)
        ...

    @property
    def name(self):
        <returns name>

    @property
    def node_id(self):
        <returns node_id>

    @property
    def device_type(self):
        <returns device type>
```

and so on...
And i need to create test, that will check if Node property is not None (has to be parametrized, management is quantity biased)

Easy way is to use getattr

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("property", ["name" ,"node_id" ,"device_type"])
def test_01_device_information(self, property):
    property = request.param
    ...
    for node in nodes:
         assert device.getattr(node, property) is not None
```

but drawback is, that this is dynamic reflection, and test will know if property exist in runtime. IDE syntaxer won't figure out missing property. Tests run trough night...

I can make a list of properties like (and syntaxer will find if any is gone):

```
        @pytest.mark.parametrize("property", [Node.name ,Node.node_id ,Node.device_type])
```

Is there a way to call that on object 'node' in that for loop? I know, I can call `__name__` on `property`, but also I think there might be better ,or different solution.
I'd be thankful for suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
for node in nodes:
    assert property.fget(node) is not None
```

Comment: Yep, that will work :) Thanks!